# Big commerce - add custom js code

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

I need to do something with ecommerce shop, built with bigcommerce.com
and I need to add custom html and css code and I can't find anywhere something like ftp access may be.
where can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to make changes to HTML and CSS files, you can edit in-browser using Edit Theme Files:
https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Editing-Stencil-Theme-Files

If you need to add a new file to the theme, or edit the Javascript files, you will need to use Stencil CLI developer tools to edit locally and package the theme:
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/installing-and-launching-stencil-1